# replace IP Address with subdomain to SSH via subdomain

Tags: networking, dns, ip, web-hosting

I SSH into a series of static IP addresses, but it's easy to forget which one is which. I'd like to replace the static IP addresses with a subdomain of a domain I own.

I.e.,

55.55.555.55 --> box1.example.com

55.55.555.56 --> box2.example.com

55.55.555.57 --> box3.example.com

I tried setting the "A Record" for my subdomain. There is now an "A Record" for box1.example.com that points to 55.55.555.55. The problem is that when I try to SSH into box1.example.com, I don't think it's pointing to 55.55.555.55, but still points to some random box where the website for my domain (example.com) is being hosted. The subdomain doesn't appear to be redirecting to the static IP address I entered when I attempt to SSH. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I use "dig box1.example.com" I see an A record for the web hosts IP address and the one I entered is nowhere to be found.

Comment: I found out why this was happening. Apparently, I had "parked" the domain. Turns out that A record entries or ignored for a parked domain. Thanks for your help. Glad this was resolved and that I don't have to memorize an endless stream of IP addresses.